# Divs sharing the total size (not percentage)

Tags: css, html

Is there away to connect the sizes of divs as I did with the frames below?
I'm talking about the `*` in `rows="*, 16"`, that takes the remaining space.

```
<frameset frameborder="0"  rows="70, *, 30">
   <frame name="toolbar" src="toolbar.html" marginwidth="8px" marginheight="8px" />

   <frameset id="lineNumFrameset" frameborder="0" cols="50, *">
      <frameset rows="*, 16">
      <frame id="other_frame" name="lineNum" src="lineNum.html" marginwidth="8px" marginheight="8px" align="top" />
      </frameset>

      <frame name="editor" src="editor.html" marginwidth="8px" marginheight="8px" />
   </frameset>

   <frame name="statusbar" src="statusbar.html" marginwidth="8px" marginheight="8px" />
</frameset>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want a fluid three column layout.

Using margins and float will work. Float your first div to the left and set it to the width of what you want the left most column width to be. Float your second div on the right and set its width. Then your third div will not float, but you'll set its left margin to the width of the left column, its right margin to the width of the right column.

There will be some issues to resolve if either of your columns are greater in height than your middle div, but that's solvable by creating a containing floated div.

Edit: added example:

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/steps/step22.htm

Comment: Can you please give me an example? Also, my divs are located one under the other, will it work with height as well?

Thanks

Comment: do not listen to frunsi, do not use tables for layout: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem is to use the `onresize` event with the viewport (`document.documentElement.clientHeight`) set on the relevant height CSS property with JavaScript.